# Unable to run Javascript to change divs

Tags: javascript

I really hope someone can help me with this Javascript issue I've been fighting for the past couple of days.

I'm trying to get 2 divs to either show or hide depending on a dropdown selection.  I have looked at various code examples here, jFiddle and other resources but all of the scripts dont work and I'm not sure why.

Raw HTML:

```
<select id="dropdown" onChange="">
<option value="blank"></option>
<option value="sd" id="SD">Header 1</option>
<option value="oc" id="OC">Header 2</option>
</select>

<div class="data"> 

<div id="div1">
<h1>Header 1</h1>
<p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
</div>

<div id="div2">
<h1>Header 2</h1>
<p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Raw Javascript:

```
("dropdown").change(function () {
if($("dropdown".option)='blank'{
    $("data").style.visibility='hidden'();}

if($("dropdown".option)='SD'{
    $("div1").style.visibility='visible'();}
    else{
        $("div2").style.visibility='hidden'();}

if($("dropdown".option)='OC'{
    $("div2").style.visibility='visible'();}
    else{
        $("div1").style.visibility='hidden'();}


});
```

If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be awesome.  Basically, what I'm trying to do is:

If dropdown selection = "this div", hide the other div

Comment: There's quite a few syntax errors above... `if($("dropdown".option)='SD'{` - not sure what's happening there. For starters - you're missing the ID selector on all your jQuery selectors (`#`)

Comment: Some of this looks like jQuery, some of it looks like raw Javascript with `$()` as a short name for `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: And some of it is just totally bogus.

Comment: @kjones I would recommend learning how to structure your code, your code is consistent which is great however its not inline with the rest of the community

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the sequencial mistakes with logic and sintaxe. When some option of div is selected, the correct is to show one and hide another.

```js
$("#dropdown").change(function() {
    if ( $("#dropdown").val() == 'sd' ) {
        $("#div1").show();
        $("#div2").hide();
    } else if ( $("#dropdown").val() == 'oc' ) {
       $("#div1").hide();
       $("#div2").show();
    } else {
       $(".data").hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown" onChange="">
<option value="blank"></option>
<option value="sd" id="SD">Header 1</option>
<option value="oc" id="OC">Header 2</option>
</select>

<div class="data"> 

<div id="div1">
<h1>Header 1</h1>
<p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
</div>

<div id="div2">
<h1>Header 2</h1>
<p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the negativity here is ridiculous!
This guy is obviously learning and kudos to that... Welcome kjones :) I recommend you continue with jQuery learn what you can, but I warn you jQuery is not the answer for everything it will in fact make you a worse programmer. Learning actual javascript touch me so much so I recommend doing so also it will make you stand out! :)

However I digress the solution here is quite simple, your overthinking it basically which jQuery here is the culprit.

If I was using jQuery I would make a plugin, because it sounds like this feature should be reusable!

```
$.fn.selectorThing = function (rootDivClass) {

  // hide all the divs which have the rootClass
  hideAllTheDivs = function () {
    $('[class^="'+ rootDivClass +'"]').hide();
  }

  // hide all the divs which have the rootClass & show the right one
  showDiv = function (val) {
    hideAllTheDivs();
    $('.'+ rootDivClass + '-' + val).show();
  }

  // run showDiv on change and pass the selected value
  this.change(function() {
    showDiv(
      $(this).find(":selected").attr('value')
    );
  });

  // initally we want to hide all of the classes data-*
  hideAllTheDivs();

  // return this so we can chain another jQuery function
  return this;
}

$('#dropdown').selectorThing('data');
```

My HTML would look something like this

```
<select id="dropdown">
<option value="blank"></option>
<option value="sd" id="SD">Header 1</option>
<option value="oc" id="OC">Header 2</option>
</select>

<div class='data-sd'>
  content
</div>
<div class='data-oc'>
  some other content
</div>
```